# hibernate define possible column values

Tags: java, hibernate, enums, annotations

while saving Enums I need to constrain the column values within a definite set, 
can this be achieved through annotation in hibernate?

or if possible make some custom annotations, something like:

```
@possibleValues({"LIKE","COMMENT","SHARE"})
public TYPEOFSERVICES getTypeOfServices() {
        return typeOfServices;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
    @Column(name = "YourColumn")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public TYPEOFSERVICES getTypeOfServices() {
        return typeOfServices;
    }
```

and you have enum:

```
public enum TYPEOFSERVICES {

    LIKE,
    COMMENT,
    SHARE;
}
```